# Virtual Functions in Derived Classes

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, virtual-functions

I have been watching several videos, and I have come to know how virtual function calls are processed through late binding.

In early binding, for lines like `ptr->func(...)`, the compiler reviews the data type for `ptr` and looks in the corresponding class for the `func(...)` definition.

While during late binding for virtual functions, `ptr` address is accessed, and then the definition is looked up in the corresponding class.

If I am right about the mechanism I have just mentioned, then why does the following code produce an error?

```cpp
class A{
   public:
       void func(){
       }
};

class B: public A{
    public:
       virtual void f4(){
           cout<<"Cunt"<<endl;
       }

};

int main(){
    A* ptr;
    B obj;
    ptr=&obj;
    ptr->f4();
    return 0;
}
```

Also, why does the below code produce the output `base` instead of the output `derived`?

```cpp
class A{
   public:
       void f4(){
           cout<<"base"<<endl;
       }
};

class B: public A{
    public:
       virtual void f4(){
           cout<<"derived"<<endl;
       }

};

int main(){
    A* ptr;
    B obj;
    ptr=&obj;
    ptr->f4();
    return 0;
}
```

Please help. Am I wrong about the mechanism?

Answer (score 2):

In class `A`, the function `f4` should be defined as `virtual` too:

```
class A {
   public:
       virtual void f4(){
           std::cout << "base" << std::endl;
       }
};
```

In your case, `f4` is non-virtual function, due to non-virtual inheritance.
One more thing, derived virtual functions should be mark as `override`, and the `virtual` is not necessary:

```
class B : public A {
public:
    void f4() override {
        std::cout << "derived" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

If you would try to mark `f4` in `B` as `override` without making it `virtual` in `A` first, you would get the compilation error: `error: ‘virtual void B::f4()’ marked ‘override’, but does not override`- which means that you won't be able to access it using `A` class pointer.

Side note: read the following post: [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Answer (score 1):

In your first example, `A` does not have a method named `f4()`, so the call to `ptr->f4()` is not valid.

In your second example, `A::f4()` is not marked as `virtual`, so the call to `ptr->f4()` does not perform virtual dispatch, and so calls `A::f4()` rather than `B::f4()`.

The solution to both problems is the same - make `f4()` be virtual in `A`, and have `B` `override` it, eg:

```cpp
class A{
   public:
       virtual void f4() {
           cout << "base" << endl;
       }
};

class B: public A{
    public:
       void f4() override {
           cout << "derived" << endl;
       }
};

int main(){
    A* ptr;
    B obj;
    ptr = &obj;
    ptr->f4();
    return 0;
}
```